# How to show buffer list while selecting text in emacs CUA mode

Tags: emacs

What key combination works for selecting buffers in CUA mode?

C-x C-x (rapidly) does not work when text is highlighted: it cuts the text.

M-x b  does not work

M-x M-b does not work

Comment: How about?:  `M-x list-buffers RET`

Comment: @lawlist  OK that works. I was trying M-x buffer<tab> (brand new to emacs).  Can I jump to the buffer list via keyboard only?

Comment: The default binding for `list-buffers` is `C-x C-b`; however, CUA mode (although I have never used it) appears to be designed to hijack `C-x` (among a few other prefixes).  If that built-in command of `C-x C-b` does not work, then you will need to set up an alternative keyboard shortcut that does not conflict with CUA mode.  Here is a basic example using the f5 key:  `(global-set-key [f5] 'list-buffers)`